# Getting divs to fill all available space, 3 columns, fixed widths, variable heights

Tags: jquery, html, css

The best way to explain this is with the below image. You can see I have 3 divs floated left with a fixed width but variable height.

**When I add a 4th I would like it to slot underneath the 2nd div because there is space available.**

I would like all following divs to use the space as efficiently as possible, slotting in where they can.

I saw a jQuery plugin achieve this once, but I don't know what the technique is called so I cannot find it!

[image: example]

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a great plugin for that - [jquery masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)